# Как объединить строки из двух файлов?

Tags: delphi

Есть два файла, содержащие равное количество строк. Мне нужно прочесть из них все строки и сохранить их в третий файл объединив одну к одной через `+`.

У меня получился вот такой код, но он не работает как следует. Какую я сделала ошибку?

```
var
  f1,f2,f3:TextFile;
  s,str:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  OpenDialog1.Options := OpenDialog1.Options + [ofAllowMultiSelect];
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
    AssignFile(f2,OpenDialog1.FileName);
    AssignFile(f3,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Rezultat.txt');
    Reset(f1); Reset(f2); Reset(f3); Rewrite(f3);

    while not Eof(f1) do begin
      Readln(f1,s,str);
      Readln(f2,s,str);
      S:=str+'+'+s;
      Writeln(f3,s,str);
    end;

    CloseFile(f1);
    CloseFile(f2);
    CloseFile(f3);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Татьяна, ну как же так, вы читаете из "первого" файла и пишете в "результирующий". А где вы читаете из "второго" файла?

Comment: а где третий файл?

Comment: Вот я как всегда зависла :). Сейчас попробую исправить. Igor, Kromster рада вашим ответам ребята.

Comment: Сделала правку и внесла изменения в коде что высше. Но все равно ошибка. Еще какие погрешности есть ?

Comment: Татьяна, не убирайте условие задачи из вопроса. Без него, код может быть непонятен или неверно понят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  f1,f2,f3:TextFile;
  s,str:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  OpenDialog1.Options := OpenDialog1.Options + [ofAllowMultiSelect];
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then 
  begin
    AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.Files[0]);
    AssignFile(f2,OpenDialog1.Files[1]);
    AssignFile(f3,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Rezultat.txt');
    Reset(f1);
    Reset(f2);
    Rewrite(f3);
    while not Eof(f1) and not Eof(f2) do 
    begin
      Readln(f1,s);
      Readln(f2,str);
      Writeln(f3,s + str);
    end;
    CloseFile(f1);
    CloseFile(f2);
    CloseFile(f3);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Вероятно будет лучше, если вы прокомментируете добавленные/измененные строки. Ответ содержащий только код, может быть бесполезен для начинающего.

Answer (score 1):

Все вопрос решила. Все работает.

```
begin
if ODialog1.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f1,ODialog1.FileName);
if ODialog2.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f2,ODialog2.FileName);
AssignFile(f3,ExtractFileDir(ODialog1.FileName)+'\Rezultat.txt');
Reset(f1); Reset(f2); Rewrite(f3);
    while not Eof(f1) do begin
        Readln(f1,s);
        Readln(f2,str);

 s:=s+'+'+str;
Writeln(f3,s);
  end;
```